# Colored dots falshes in 3D-games on Gefoce RTX 2070

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

I am having blue/purple flashes in several 3D games.

You can see them above the door on this example of the Witcher 3:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cy-FoHGwBR0&feature=youtu.be

[image: age]

I am using a Gefoce RTX 2070, latest driver (441.66) on Windows 10 (1903).
I have had this now since several months (i.e. across the previous windows and graphics driver versions since that time)

They mostly show up on the top half, top left corner of the screen.

Any idea where this could come from and how to remove this?

thanks!

Comment: As it is seems to be an ingame recording it's probably part of the game or due to some tool you installed across all of those Windows versions.

Comment: @Seth it's def. not part of the game since I have it in several different games.

Comment: Any chance we could have a still image of it in the question?

Comment: @Smock sure, added it!

Comment: Thanks. At first i thought it was some fancy lens flare type thing. So I watched the video too, and they seem to flash all over the place, popping in and out, not related to camera movement or anything. Whatever it is, its happening during render, rather than an artifact after the fact (to be caught on video cap). I'd contact support for your GPU manufacturer.

Comment: If you look at around 0:14 in the video there's also a big blue rectangle that flashes up. I'd post a screenshot but you can't in comments :(

Comment: @Smock yeah I have seen that